# How to manage an array of pointers to a struct

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following struct:

```
struct Item
{
    Item* nextPtr;
    int intKey;
    int intValueLength;
};
```

Based of such a struct I need to maintain several linked lists, which means I need to keep track of one head pointer for each one. I have thought about using an array (HEADS) which will contain a head pointer for each list. The number of lists is variable and will be calculated at run time so I am defining the array dynamically as follows:

```
int t = 10;
Item* HEADS = new Item[t];
```

Firstly, I need to initialize each head pointer to NULL because the linked lists are empty when the program runs. How do I do this initialization?

```
for (int i = 0; i  <= t - 1; i++)
    // Initialize each element of HEADS to NULL.
```

And, of course, I will also need to update each element of HEADS with the proper pointer to a linked list (when inserting and deleting items) and also to get the value of each head pointer to display the elements of each list.

I have seen other posts similar to this one in the forum but I am still confused, that is why I am asking my specific situation.

Is this a good approach?
I will very much appreciate your advice.

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Why not just a `std::vector<std::list<Item>>`? You don't need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @NicoSchertler - excellent point. Part of learning C++ is learning the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the common way to write the initialization `for` loop would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < t ; i++)
  HEADS[i] = NULL;
```

Or you could write

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < t ; HEADS[i++] = NULL);
```

which is slightly more compact.

As to the question of whether an array of pointers is a good idea or not - if you're going to have a variable number of lists, perhaps you should use a linked list of pointers to other linked lists.

I do wonder about your data structure, though. In it you have a pointer to the next element in the list, a key value, and a the length of the value, but you don't appear to have a reference to a value - unless the "key" is really the value, in which case you have mixed terminology - that is, you refer to something in one place as a "key" and in another as a "value. Perhaps you need a pointer to a "value"? But I don't know what you're trying to do here so I just thought I'd note that issue.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Good approach? That's a very, very dependent on things. Good for a student starting to learn C, maybe. Good for a real C++ programmer? Absolutely not. If you really want to create a linked-list, you should make a class that encompasses each element of these, and dynamically add elements. This is how `std::list`, for example, works. (`std::list` is doubly-linked list, and way more complicated).

Here's a sample class of how this should look like (off the top of my head; haven't compiled it, but should work):

```
struct LinkedList
{
    Item* list;
    int size = 0;
    LinkedList() //constructor of this class/struct, it's the function that will be called once you create an object of LinkedList
    {
        list = nullptr; //don't use NULL, it's deprecated (this is for C++11, or change it back to NULL if you insist on using C++98)
    }
    addItem(const int& key)
    {
        Item item; //construct a new item
        item.intKey = key; //fill the value in the item
        Item* newList = new Item[size+1]; //create the new list with one more element
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //copy the old list to the new list
        {
            newList[i] = list[i]; //copy element by element
        }
        list[size] = item; //fill in the new item
        if(size > 0)
        {
            list[size - 1].nextPtr = &list[size]; //assign "next pointer" for previous element
        }
        size = size+1; //increase the size of the list
    }
    ~linkedList()
    {
        if(list != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] list;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is better, but it's still **far** from optimal. However, this is how C++ should be used. You create *objects* and deal with them. What you did above is more like C, not C++.

To my code, you have to call:

```
LinkedList myList;
myList.addItem(55);
```

There are many things to do here to make this optimal. I'll mention a few:

In my code, every time you add an item, a new array is allocated. This is bad! `std::vector` solves this problem by allocating a bigger size than needed (for example, you add 1 item, it reserves 10, but uses only 1, and doesn't tell you that). Once you need more than 10, say 11, it reserves 20, maybe. This optimizes performance.

Try to read my code and understand it. You'll learn so much. Ask questions; I'll try to answer. And my recommendation is: get a C++ book, and start reading.